# Generic static create method in base class that takes an object whose keys match class accessors

Tags: typescript

Take these classes:

```
abstract class Shape {
   static create<T>(this:T,data:{[K in keyof typeof this]:T[K]}):T {
      //creates a new instance of the class this is called on
      //and sets each of the keys
   }
}
class Child extends Shape { 
  set name(val:string) {
    //..
  }
}
```

What I'm looking to do is this, with strict types on the keys and values of the object passed as data:

```
Child.create({
  name:"hello",//valid
  somethingElse:1,//invalid
});
```

The important part is that the static create function is only defined once. Creating an instance and setting the keys works fine, but I want the editor to auto fill and type check the keys and values passed to `create()`.

Comment: `this` in a static method is the *constructor* type, not the instance type.  Presumably you're looking for something like [this instead](https://tsplay.dev/mALV4N)?  If so I'll write up an answer (or find an appropriate dupe target).  Otherwise, what am I missing?